# Double Menu when Scrolling (More specifically YAML)

Tags: javascript, css, menu, scroll, yaml-css

this is my first StackOverflow post. So I hope my question fits the standards.

I'm working on creating my own website using the YAML CSS Framework. ( http://www.yaml.de/docs/index.html )

On that page, they have it so as you scroll, the navigation menu stays at the top of the screen.
When I downloaded the framework, I found the below code in their domscript.js file.
So I understand that they added a class so it would stick.

What I would like to do is have a second menu of the same kind with different links right below it.
I copied and pasted the html code for the menu right below it and a second one did appear.
But as I scroll down, only the first one stays.

Any ideas on how I can get the second one to stay as well?

```
if (hOffset < top) {
    if (nav.data(stickyClass) !== true) {
        nav.addClass(stickyClass).data(stickyClass,true);
    }
} else {
    if (nav.data(stickyClass) !== false) {
        nav.removeClass(stickyClass).data(stickyClass,false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because an `ID` can use only once. If you want to this type of menu you have to create another id & copy the .js file & change the `ID` in that .js file.
I think this will work.